# javascript: if radio button is selected, on submit wait 2 seconds, then show alert

Tags: javascript, radio-button, settimeout, onsubmit

I am trying to set a radio button so that if it is selected, on submit wait 2 seconds, then throw up an alert.  This feels pretty close but not working:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" id="email" value="email" onsubmit="setTimeout(function() { alert('You chose email'); },2000);">
```

My submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="choice" value="choice">
```

Answer (score 2):

`onsubmit` applies to a `<form>`, not a `<button>`. You'll need to put your submit button *and* your radio buttons inside a `<form>`, then you can add the `onsubmit` to the form tag.

Alternately, if you just want to create a popup when the radio button is changed, you can use `onclick` attribute of the radio button, e.g.

#### Update: Example using jQuery

Assuming you have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="email" value="email">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can trigger an event when the form is submitted like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    if($("#email").is(':checked')) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            alert('You chose email'); 
        }, 2000);
    }
    event.preventDefault();  // prevent page from being reloaded
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to switch `onsubmit` attribute to `onclick` and put it on the submit button.. and something like this for the function it calls:

```
// javascript
function submit() {
  if (document.getElementById('#email').checked == true) {
    setTimeout(function () {alert('you chose mail')}, 2000)
  }
}

//html
<input type="radio" name="option" id="email" value="email">
<button type="submit" name="choice" value="choice" onclick="submit()">
```

Comment: Thanks @Egor Egorov.  That looks like what I need, but it's not working for me..?  Instead of ('#checkboxid') I should have ('email') - right?

Comment: That's right, just don't forget the # in front of the id name :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var submit = false;
 $('form').submit(function(e) {
        if($('#email').is(':checked')) { 
   setTimeout(function() {
    alert("it's checked"); 
    submit = true;
    $("form").submit(); // if needed
   },2000);
    if(!submit)
              e.preventDefault();
  }
    });
```

```css
.container {
 width: 600px;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="email" value="email">
        <button type="submit" name="choice" value="choice">Test</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You guys are magic with those snippets. Both do just what I need, but I can't get mine to work :((  The form posts to a php script which performs several things including downloading a file. All that works fine, but on post does it take away the focus from the javascript, or something like that?

Comment: This one will submit form after `alert`. Then only it will post the value to php script

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of things you should get straight to achieve what you are asking for. Give this one a go - it tells you if you have chosen email or not after 2 seconds.

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(sayit,2000);
});
var sayit = function() { 
  if( $('#email').prop('checked') ) {
    alert('You chose email');
  }
  else {
    alert('You didn\' chose anything');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="email" value="email">
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" name="choice" value="choice">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```